# Realm change in change listener

Tags: android, loops, triggers, realm, rx-java

I try to replicate database trigger function with Realm with Rx. Once I get RealmList emitted, I do some stuff with it and save. Sadly, this results into Realm's change listener to be executed again, emitting the list over and over again.

Dummy example:

```
realm.where(MyRealmObject.class)
            .equalTo("state", "new")
            .findAll()
            .asObservable()
            .flatMap(new Func1<RealmResults<MyRealmObject>, Observable<MyRealmObject>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<MyRealmObject> call(RealmResults<MyRealmObject> list) {
                    return Observable.from(list);
                }
            })
            .subscribe(new Action1<MyRealmObject>() {
                @Override
                public void call(final MyRealmObject object) {
                    realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                        @Override
                        public void execute(Realm realm) {
                            // do any realm change
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
```

Once I commit the transaction in subscriber, new RealmList is emited from observable. I know why this happens, I just don't see any way how to workaround this.

This takes us to my question. Is there any way how to replicate trigger functionality with realm where I will do any realm change?

Answer (score 0):

Workaround can be built with helper stream determing whether next item from db should be consumed. Every data store into db should be accompanied with write into helper stream. Running test below yields:

```
upstream: IgnoreAction{action='start', ignoreNext=false}   
result: 1   
result: 2   
result: 3   
upstream: IgnoreAction{action='1', ignoreNext=true}   
upstream: IgnoreAction{action='2', ignoreNext=true}   
upstream: IgnoreAction{action='3', ignoreNext=true}
```

So, first data ("start") is consumed, and writes triggered in onNext are ignored.

```
@Test
public void rxIgnore() throws Exception {

MockDb mockDb = new MockDb();

BehaviorSubject<Boolean> ignoreNextStream = BehaviorSubject.create(false);
Observable<String> dataStream = mockDb.dataSource();

dataStream.zipWith(ignoreNextStream, Data::new)
        .doOnNext(action -> System.out.println("upstream: " + action))
        .filter(Data::isTakeNext)
        .flatMap(__ -> Observable.just(1, 2, 3))
        .subscribe(new Observer<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(Integer val) {
                System.out.println("result: " + val);
                ignoreNextStream.onNext(true);
                mockDb.data(String.valueOf(val));
            }
        });

mockDb.data("start");

Observable.empty().delay(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES).toBlocking().subscribe();
}

private static class Data {
private final String action;
private final boolean ignoreNext;

public Data(String action, boolean ignoreNext) {
    this.action = action;
    this.ignoreNext = ignoreNext;
}

public boolean isTakeNext() {
    return !ignoreNext;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "IgnoreAction{" +
            "action='" + action + '\'' +
            ", ignoreNext=" + ignoreNext +
            '}';
}
}

private static class MockDb {

private final Subject<String, String> subj = PublishSubject.<String>create()
                                            .toSerialized();

public void data(String action) {
    subj.onNext(action);
}

Observable<String> dataSource() {
    return subj;
}
}
```